# ComboBox c# outside form

Tags: c#, class, combobox

I have a winform that contain a comboBox. My question is : how i can use the comboBox outside that form, inside of a class ?
Here s some picture maybe it s easier to understand

[image]

[image]

Comment: Makes not much sense. Try to explain your problem better, also, don't show screenshots but paste the relevant code here. You can format it with the `Code`-button(curly brackets in the editor).

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the reference to the `ComboBox` in the constructor of the class:

```
public MyClass{

   private Combobox cbox;

   public MyClass(Combobox box){
     cbox = box;

   }
}
```

Although, I would refrain from doing this. It is definitely not the right way to handle your problem. You are creating unnecessary dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that. You would create a needless dependency of class1 to form1. Think about your architecture!

If you absolutely want to, you should provide a reference of your form to the class and access it via the form.

Comment: Here s the real example : I define a semi transparent brush and the first value, 153 represents the opacity. So I wanted to make a combobox filled with 3 opacity values(100 ,75,50) and when the user select one of the value , that value should replace 153. Not really 153 but the variable i will put there.
SolidBrush semiTransBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(153, 255, 255, 255));

Comment: You should seperate GUI and model. Poll the model for changes or implement events in Class1.